# Двусторонняя привязка JavaFx property к переменной из другого потока

Tags: java, javafx

Мне нужно связать изменяющуюся переменную из своего потока с Property из JavaFx. В теории это должно мне позволить привязать свой плеер к контролам из JavaFx. Я даже написал обертку для Property, но меня не покидает ощущение, что что-то не так, возможно я изобретаю велосипед. Устанавливать/получать значение Property не из JavaFx потока вроде как нельзя, а для этого надо использовать Platform.runLater/ChangeEvent, но в этом случае возникают следующие проблемы:

- Эхо. Когда старые значения снова прилетают через слушатель.
- Рассинхронизация. Когда в одном месте одно значение, а в другом другое. Возникает при параллельном изменении значений.
- Затирание значений. Когда мы берем значение из Property, проверяем его, думаем, что оно не изменилось и пишем туда новое, а на самом деле затираем изменившееся значение.

**Обертка:**

```
package javafxapplication1;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;

class FxPropertyAdapter<T> {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FxPropertyAdapter.class.getName());

    private volatile T value;
    private final Property<T> property;
    private boolean listenerEnabled = true;
    private final CountDownLatch initializedLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private volatile Runnable onInitializeHandler = null;
    private volatile BiConsumer<T, T> onChangeHandler = null;

    public FxPropertyAdapter(Property<T> property) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(property);
        this.property = property;
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            value = property.getValue();
            property.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (listenerEnabled) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        updateValue(newValue);
                    }
                }
            });
            synchronized (this) {
                initializedLatch.countDown();
                if (onInitializeHandler != null) {
                    try {
                        onInitializeHandler.run();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Error in initializeHandler.", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Runnable getOnInitializeHandler() {
        return onInitializeHandler;
    }

    public synchronized void setOnInitializeHandler(Runnable onInitializeHandler) {
        this.onInitializeHandler = onInitializeHandler;
        if (isInitialized() && this.onInitializeHandler != null) {
            try {
                this.onInitializeHandler.run();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Error in onInitializeHandler.", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public BiConsumer<T, T> getOnChangeHandler() {
        return onChangeHandler;
    }

    public void setOnChangeHandler(BiConsumer<T, T> onChangeHandler) {
        this.onChangeHandler = onChangeHandler;
    }

    public Property<T> getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    /**
     * Позволяет не упустить обновления, произведённые в JavaFx. Если JavaFx
     * успеет обновить значение, то мы увидим несоответствие, если запланирует
     * обновление, тогда то значение, которое мы сюда передали, будет затёрто
     * начатым обновлением из JavaFx. Но местный обработчик изменения все же
     * сработает.
     *
     * @param expect
     * @param update
     * @return
     */
    public synchronized boolean compareAndSet(T expect, T update) {
        if (expect == getValue()) {
            setValue(update);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public T getValue() {
        requireInitialized();
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * При установлении значения приоритет всегда на стороне JavaFx. Если
     * параллельно менять значения в JavaFx и в другом потоке, то из этого
     * потока значения не будут успевать попадать в постоянно меняющийся
     * Property. Однако, они будут попадать в onChangeHandler данного класса.
     *
     * С другой стороны, у нас есть доступ к самому Property и мы можем
     * установить ему значение через Platform.runLater.
     *
     * @param value
     */
    public synchronized void setValue(T value) {
        requireInitialized();
        if (this.value == value) {
            return;
        }
        T oldValue = this.value;
        updateValue(value);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            listenerEnabled = false;
            /**
             * Если JavaFx обновит значение до этого метода, то мы просто
             * обновим значение в обоих потоках.
             *
             * Если JavaFx начнёт обновлять значение до вызова метода, но не
             * успеет захватить доступ к объекту, то проверка спасает от разных
             * значений. В противном случае было бы запланировано изменение
             * Property без слушателя, а далее отработал бы ожидающий JavaFx
             * поток, который бы задал переменной старое значение, а это уже
             * рассинхронизация.
             *
             * Синхронизация нужная, чтобы текущий поток не затёр значение из
             * JavaFx вызовом updateValue(value), без синхронизации JavaFx может
             * пролезть между проверкой старого значения и обновлением значения,
             * в итоге JavaFx значение затрётся, что приведёт к разным
             * значениям.
             */
            if (property.getValue().equals(oldValue)) {
                property.setValue(value);
            }
            listenerEnabled = true;
        });
    }

    public boolean isInitialized() {
        return initializedLatch.getCount() == 0;
    }

    private void updateValue(T value) {
        T oldValue = this.value;
        this.value = value;
        if (isInitialized()) {
            try {
                onChangeHandler.accept(oldValue, value);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Error in onChangeHandler.", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void requireInitialized() {
        if (!isInitialized()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("FxPropertyAdapter isn't initialized yet.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Пример:**

```
package javafxapplication1;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleFloatProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class JavaFXApplication extends Application {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(pb);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            SimpleFloatProperty slp = new SimpleFloatProperty();
            FxPropertyAdapter<Number> fpa = new FxPropertyAdapter<>(slp);
            fpa.setOnChangeHandler((from, to) -> {
                System.out.println(String.format("Value have been changed from %s to %s.", from, to));
            });
            CountDownLatch initializedLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            fpa.setOnInitializeHandler(() -> {
                pb.progressProperty().bindBidirectional(slp);
                initializedLatch.countDown();
            });
            try {
                initializedLatch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            int sign = +1;
            for (float i = .0f; i >= 0; i += .01f * sign) {
                if (i > 1) {
                    sign = -sign;
                }
                fpa.setValue(i);
                try {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100 - (int) (i * 100));
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    return;
                }
            }
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5000), new KeyValue(slp, 1)));
            timeline.setCycleCount(2);
            timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
            timeline.play();
        });
        t1.setDaemon(true);
        t1.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: не совсем понимаю, что вы хотите сделать. вы описываете как вы делаете, но не что хотите получить.

Comment: Что хотел, вроде то и получил, но есть сомнения по поводу решения. Задача распространенная, странно, что я не нашел готового обкатанного решения, возможно я его пропустил или есть какой-то другой подход в решении этой задачи. Хотя возможно это уже паранойя. Логика не тривиальная, этот компонент ляжет в фундамент кода, боюсь наполучать дедлоков в уже большом объеме кода в будущем.

Comment: я не понял, что вы хотите  сделать. по этому не могу сказать правильно вы решили или нет.

Comment: А так?
Хочу в Thread в цикле читать и обновлять значение переменной timestamp без задержек на синхронизацию, например не ждать JavaFxThread. 
Изменения, сделанные в Thread должны передаваться на JavaFx ползунок. Но при этом, если ползунок будет сдвинут пользователем, то и переменная должна измениться.

Comment: В начале цикла хочу сохранять текущее значение переменной в локальную переменную localTimestamp, далее идет воспроизведение куска видео, далее опять возвращаемся в начало цикла, если localTimestamp == timestamp, то заменяем timestamp на новое значение, если нет, то начинаем воспроизведение с другого места, которое указано в timestamp.

Comment: если на секунду абстрагироваться от конкретного плеера, то вы хотите сделать отдельную компоненту? я не понимаю зачем вам что-то делать в другом потоке?

Comment: Абстрагироваться, наверное, не получится, это и есть основная проблема, так как важно, чтобы цикл выполнялся без задержек в итерациях, к тому же покадровое чтение видеопотока не быстрая опеация, а если учесть, что параллельно будет воспроизводиться 5 – 10 каналов, то все это дело в JavaFx потоке, думаю, уже не получится провернуть. Поэтому проще отдельно написать плеер и прикрутить его к JavaFx как внешнюю компоненту.

Comment: Кажется я понял. Вы смешиваете UI и то, что к нему не относится. Вам нужно сделать модель для вашего приложения, а UI просто отображает, что в ней происходит.

Comment: Я действительно в своем потоке отслеживаю модель данных, а та обертка, которую я написал, это попытка синхронизировать мою модель с UI через Platform.runLater и ChangeListener, хотя проще это можно сделать из самого потока JavaFx через Timeline и ChangeListener. Так как мы читаем данные прямо из модели, то исчезаю описанные мной проблемы.

Если я вас правильно понял, то думаю, что это и есть ответ на мое неудовлетворение своим велосипедом. Могу пометить ответ, если добавите.